# Deleting all tags on a question

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's say that a user with the ability to make tags makes a rather poor choice and creates an entirely off topic post ([motivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471583/programmers-god-closed)).
Let's say that they create and attach tags called `[Kittens]` and `[Rainbows]`.
Neither of these tags are useful in anyway, so their mere existence poisons the tag pool, and obviously they should be removed.
Here comes the question, since the question must have a tag, what tag should we keep there if both tags should be deleted?

Comment: Doesn't it become `[untagged]` if all tags are deleted?

Comment: kittehs iz alwuz on topik.

Comment: @Kenny: you can't actually remove all tags in the normal UI. You *can* however add the "untagged" tag explicitly..

Comment: @KennyTM it wants a tag

Comment: @Shog9 I really hope that tag is temporary and doesn't start getting used to get around tagging stuff

Comment: @Michael: it's an artifact of the [subjective] removal. A number of people still go through it periodically and retag / close / delete as-needed. I *suspect* it'll be blacklisted eventually...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is no appropriate tag to be applied on a question, the question doesn't belongs on Stack Overflow. It should be closed and/or deleted, not retagged.

Comment: Boy, did i pick a bad day to burn through all my close votes...

Comment: Boy do i wish i had some close votes for the abomination that is my motivating question

Comment: You can flag post for moderator attention if they need to be closed/deleted. Moderator can close them too and they don't have limit per day.

Comment: @James:  I just supplied the last close vote.  Now if I just remember to hunt it down and vote to delete....

Comment: @David: Too late. Looks like Marc just got there.

Comment: @mmyers:  Hey, my name's on the voted-to-close list.  Not to mention it's been taken out permanently by a diamond mod, so I don't have to remember to track it down later.